# Using stored procedures for repository pattern with Service Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

**Background**

In my web application, I create stored procedures and then create an edmx file to use the stored procedures to handle all the database interaction.

But I started to wonder if I'm doing this right because, as you'll see in the example below,

1. I'm instantiating two instances of `Context` every time the `Controller` gets called even when the called method doesn't require database work
2. I'm instantiating an instances of `Context` in each repository, so when a request needs to get data from Repository A and B, I have two instances of `Context`.

**Repository A**

```
public class RepositoryA
{
            private readonly Context _context;

            public RepositoryA()
            {
                _context = new Context();
            }

            public List<CLASS> GetA(int id)
            {
                return _context.GetByID(id);
            }
}
```

**Repository B**

```
public class RepositoryB
{
            private readonly Context _context;

            public RepositoryB()
            {
                _context = new Context();
            }

            public List<CLASS> GetB(int id)
            {
                return _context.GetByID(id);
            }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class Controller
{
            private readonly IRepositoryA _reposA;
            private readonly IRepositoryB _reposB;

            public Controller() : this(new RepositoryA(), new RepositoryB())
            {}

            public Controller(IRepositoryA a, IRepositoryB b)
            {
                _respoA = a;
                _reposB = b;
            }

            public ActionResult METHOD()
            {
                //do something with both RepositoryA and RepositoryB 
                var dataFromA = _reposA.GetA(ID); 
                var dataFromB = _reposB.GetB(ID);

                return View(someData);
            }
}
```

Now the question is: I'm not sure if this is supposed to be the normal implementation, so I've been trying to figure out how I can set this up in more efficient and testable way, and I tried something like this.

I believe that this design solves some of my concerns:

1. Service gets called every time Controller gets called, but Context doesn't get instantiated every time (Context gets instantiated per request).
2. When a service requires both Repository A and B, it uses the same Context

However, with how `Service` is set up, I can't unit test `Service` with test data because I can't use my mock repositories.

```
public class Controller
{
        private Service _service;

        public Controller()
        {
            _service =  new Service();
        }

        public ActionResult METHOD()
        {
            _service.DoSomethingWithRepoAandB(); 

            return View();
        }
}

public class Service
{
            public void DoSomethingWithRepoAandB()
            {
                 using (var _context = new Context())
                 {
                     RepositoryA a = new RepositoryA(_context);
                     RepositoryB b = new RepositoryB(_context);
                     something = a.DoSomethingWithA();
                     otherThing = b.DoOtherThingWithB();
                 }                    
            }
}
```

So, I'm thinking I should set up `Service` like this.

With this design, `Context` will be instantiated every time `Controller` gets called (unless I instantiate `Service` in a `Controller` method), but I can unit test by passing mock repositories.

```
public class Service
{
    private readonly Context _context;
    private IRepositoryA _a;
    private IRepositoryB _b;

    public Service()
    {
         _context = new Context();
         _a = new RepositoryA(_context);
         _b = new RepositoryB(_context);
    }        

    // Pass Mock Repositories in unit tests
    public Service(RepositoryA a, RepositoryB b)
    {
        _a = a;
        _b = b;
    }

    public void DoSomethingWithRepoAandB()
    {
        something = _a.DoSomethingWithA();
        otherThing =_b.DoOtherThingWithB();  
    }
}
```

Am I doing this completely wrong or on the ok track? I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: Are your repositories disposing of the context at any point? Is it acceptable that the context may be stale at some point?

Comment: @TiesonT. Right now it's not disposed explicitly.

Comment: What function does your repository give your architecture? You could cut it out and use the context directly in the service classes. That would avoid the problems with sharing entities across multiple context instances and simplify your code. Inject the context into your service constructor and inject your service into your controller. If you're concerned about the context instantiation, you can split the controller to move out the db-less actions. You can [mock the context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429(v=vs.113).aspx) so the service can be tested.

Comment: Have you checked out something like this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: @Jasen, The repositories do things like saving data, get data or a list by id, etc. I thought about having one repository for all models/viewmodels, but I wanted to keep them loosely coupled. I'll read about mocking the context. Thank you!

Comment: But ask yourself what have you gained by wrapping the context in another layer of (respository) classes?

Comment: @TiesonT. Yes, I read the article and I wasn't sure how I'm passing the context from Service and also be able to test Service. I'm thinking the post James marked as duplicate shows the idea. Thank you!

Comment: @Jasen You are absolutely right and that's so true... I think for this one I could use one repository for all as I don't have many different entities, but I was also curious if there's any way to achieve both. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Your services should NOT have any information about your context, that information should only be accessible by the repository, following SOLID principles.

The access of your layers should be as follows:

Controller -> Service -> Repository -> Context

On your IRepository interfaces, you will have the methods you're going to call, and you either instantiate them manually, but to implement it correctly, you'll have to setup your dependency injection.

Also, your Repositories constructors dont receive any context as a parameter, so you cant do something like this:

```
RepositoryA a = new RepositoryA(_context);
```

On another point, your controller shouldn't access repositories as well, as it breaks your architecture

```
public ActionResult METHOD()
    {
        //do something with both RepositoryA and RepositoryB 
        var dataFromA = _reposA.GetA(ID);
        var dataFromB = _reposB.GetB(ID);

        return View(someData);
    }
```

Here's the correct code, for further understanding:

```
public class RepositoryA : IRepositoryA
{
    private readonly Context _context;

    public RepositoryA(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public List<CLASS> GetA(int id)
    {
        return _context.GetByID(id);
    }
}

public interface IRepositoryA
{
    List<CLASS> GetA(int id);
}

public class RepositoryB : IRepositoryB
{
    private readonly Context _context;

    public RepositoryB(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public List<CLASS> GetB(int id)
    {
        return _context.GetByID(id);
    }
}

public interface IRepositoryB
{
    List<CLASS> GetB(int id);
}

public class Controller
{
    private IService _service;

    public Controller(IService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public ActionResult METHOD(int id)
    {
        //do something with both RepositoryA and RepositoryB THROUGH the service. The service needs to hold the business rules, and repositories should only care about querying data and handling contexts.
        var data = _service.DoSomethingWithRepoAandB(id)

        return View(data);
    }

}

public class Service : IService
{
    private IRepositoryA _a;
    private IRepositoryB _b;

    // Pass Mock Repositories in unit tests -> PS: You can't have 2 constructors if you're using dependency injection.
    public Service(RepositoryA a, RepositoryB b)
    {
        _a = a;
        _b = b;
    }

    public void DoSomethingWithRepoAandB(int id)
    {
        var something = _a.GetA(id);
        var otherThing = _b.GetB(id);
    }
}

public interface IService
{
    void DoSomethingWithRepoAandB(int id);
}

public class Bootstrapper
{
    //this class should be in a separated assembly, responsible for handling the dependency injection. Using Simple Injection syntax just as an example

    public static void RegisterServices(Container container) //IoC Container
    {
        container.Register<IService, Service>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register<IRepositoryA, RepositoryA>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register<IRepositoryB, RepositoryB>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register<Context>(() => {
            var options = // Configure your ContextOptions here
            return new Context(options);
        });
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    //This is your startup configuration if you're using WebApi. If you're on MVC, you can do this on your Global.asax
    public void Configuration()
    {
        var container = new Container();
        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle(); 
        BootStrapper.RegisterServices(container);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll check your method and the link posted by James. Thank you!

Comment: This is all nice until you work in a real application where the context has to be shared among repositories due to basic need of atomic transactions, then this entire architecture falls to pieces. Also, that "correct code" fails the DI pattern on both repositories.

Comment: Camilo Terevinto, if you are sharing your context among repositories, you're doing it wrong. I didn't bother to add dependency injection on the repositories for the context as it was only meant to be an explanation, not a full implementation. And yes, this works perfectly in a real world application, as I've worked in many companies using similar architectures. But I understand, it's a lot easier to criticise someone instead of helping.

Comment: Anyway, ill edit my answer and add your beloved DI on the repos as well